# useBaseName is not available in history npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

I am using [history package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) for getting the useBaseName like this

```
import { useBasename } from "history";
```

But it is coming as **undefined**. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

My history package version is **4.7.2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useBasename` has been removed from `history` version 4, it is only available in earlier versions.

In the current version of `history`, you can set the base name as an option when you create a history, e.g.:

```
const history = createHistory({
  basename: "/the/base"
})
```

See also: [history documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#using-a-base-url)